# Decorate an ActiveRecord during load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns, activerecord, decorator

I have a Rails ActiveRecord model that I want to return decorated results when I perform a query using my_method, but only once the query has executed and returned results.

In other words:

`MyModel.where(condition).my_method.where(another_condition)`

Will return an ActiveRelation. My method my_method does not disturb the chaining of queries as long as the results are lazy loaded.

`MyModel.where(condition).my_method.where(another_condition).all`

Will return MyDecoratedResult.

One way I could do this would be to have my_method do the decoration upon call, and intelligently forward subsequent requests to it's contents (the ActiveRelation). I don't mind this way, but would prefer a technique that requires less intelligence.

Would like to hear some ideas about other ways to achieve my goal. Other than the way I've mentioned, I can only think to extend ActiveRelation.

Thanks!
Max

Comment: The proper way would be to use scopes (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes), or indeed having `my_method` the ActiveRecord::Relation instance. Without knowing what `my_method` does, any advice here is moot, though. Replying mainly for the sake of Google searches.